# Выполнить функцию после клика по ссылки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно, используя обработчик событий (jquery или js) перёд переходом по ссылке (после клика по ссылке), выполнить функцию. Для ПК работает:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a', fn_check)
```

Но для мобильных телефонов не работает, страница перезагружается раньше чем выполниться функции.

Использовать тег onclick нету возможности.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю что можно попробовать следующий алгоритм.Отменить стандартные действия браузера на данную ссылку.На подобии как сделано в этом коде

```
<a id="myAnchor" href="https://www.yandex.ru/">Перейти на сайт Яндекс</a>
<script>
var myAnchor = document.getElementById("myAnchor");
myAnchor.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log("Мы отменили стандартное действие браузера");
  event.preventDefault();
}, false);
</script>
```

а потом когда выполниться твоя fn_check,в конце ее

искусственно  перейти на страницу window.location.href = "my.url" в этой же вкладке

или в новой window.open('http://example.com');

Понятно что костыль, может у кого то будет более лаконичное решение, но как говориться, разные варианты это не отсутствия вариантов.